# How enable auto rebuild spring boot project in eclipse and/or STS ides

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to active auto rebuild in `eclipse`/`STS` ides in `spring boot` project , 
i tried mark check to `project`-> `build Automatically` but it's dons't working with me the below image describe what i do .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot has an interesting feature called **Hot Swapping** detailed in their [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)

You can use it in mosly every modern IDE (Eclipse, STS or Intellij). It includes reloading static content, java classes and other stuffs.

Comment: Please validate the answer for others to see? You enabled the Hot Swapping?